# Display first 100 Integers in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am very new to prolog and I am trying to code a simple program which will display the first 100 integers.

```
is_integer(0).
is_integer(X) :-
    is_integer(Y),
    ( Y >= 100, ! ; X is Y + 1 ).
```

It works well but when we ask if 2.1 is an integer then it replies "true". This is because 2.1 is between 0 and 100.

But I want a program which will strictly display the first 100 Integers only.Could someone help me with this please. 
Thanks!

Comment: Note: there are 101 integers in the range [0;100]. :)

Comment: What are the first integers? Isn't -1 one of them?

Comment: your explanation `This is because 2.1 is between 0 and 100` is wrong: just try `?- is_integer(101.1).`

Answer (score 3):

I think this matches your style in the question if you don't want to use predefined functions like [`between(0, 100, X)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=between/3):

```
between0_100(X) :-
    (var(X) -> true ; X >= 0),  % either X is unbound or >= 0.
    between0_100(0, X).

between0_100(X, X).
between0_100(X, Y) :-
    Z is X + 1,                 % increment X
    Z =< 100,                   % and test if it is <= 100
    between0_100(Z, Y).         % recurse
```

```
?- between0_100(X).
X = 0 ;
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
…
X = 98 ;
X = 99 ;
X = 100 ;
false.

?- between0_100(2.1).
false
```

Comment: +1 for a solution that displays the integers *without* using impure predicates like `format/2` and `writeln/1`.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "display"?

The (very standard) predicate `between/3` is defined along the lines of:

`between(Lower, Upper, N)` is true when *N* >= *Lower* and *N* =< *Upper*. If *N* is an integer, it will succeed or fail, and throw an error if it is not an integer. If *N* is a free variable it will enumerate solutions by backtracking. I am quite certain you can find reasonable implementations of `between/3` elsewhere on StackOverflow.

Or do you mean that you type in:

```
?- first_100_ints.
```

And you get:

```
0
1
2
3
4
...
99
```

?

You could do this as follows:

```
first_100_ints :-
    next_int(0, 100).

next_int(X, Upper) :-
    (   X < Upper
    ->  format('~d~n', [X]),
        succ(X, X1),
        next_int(X1, Upper)
    ;   true
    ).
```

This is one "cheap" way to do it. But keep in mind that this is not how you would want to write a Prolog program, normally. One somewhat better way would be to use the built-ins `between/3` and `forall/3`:

```
?- forall(between(0, 99, X), format('~d~n', [X])).
```

This is equvalent to:

```
?- \+ (between(0, 99, X), \+ format('~d~n', [X])).
```

which reads something along the lines of, "There is no number between 0 and 99 (inclusive) for which you cannot print out the number". See [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=forall2).

There are other things you can do, depending on what your exact goal is.

Answer (score 1):

I second @Kay's answer. If it is possible, don't use side-effects and use the [prolog-toplevel](/questions/tagged/prolog-toplevel) instead!

If your Prolog implementation offers [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd), you could do it like this:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

?- X in 0..100, indomain(X).
X = 0.  ;
X = 1   ;
X = 2   ;
%                                 % ... lots of more answers ...
X = 99  ;
X = 100 ;
false.                            % query terminates universally
```

Comment: Even more efficient leaving out `indomain(X)`!

Comment: @false. You're right. But being parallel to `between/3` (w.r.t. the answer sequence) has its merits, too.